# Magento2: How to get cart rules applied product details on product view page and cart page?

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart

I want to display free shipping product promotion message on product view & cart page. But I cannot be getting promotion details.

Magento2: How to get cart rules applied product details on product view page and cart page?

Magento 2.0